# SSMS localdb to Power BI Gateway not connecting

Tags: powerbi, ssms, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have SSMS installed on my laptop along with a localdb I created:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a connection with my localdb (in Power BI Service) and my local SQL db via my gateway but I keep getting an error. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am uploading a report from Power BI Report Builder. I am able to connect using the same credentials on Power BI Report Builder. However, when I enter the credentials on Power BI Service I get an error. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Try to install and use the normal SQL Server instead of LocalDB. When connecting to LocalDB, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically created and started, but I'm not sure that the Power BI Gateway supports that.

Comment: You should post this as an answer so that I could mark it as a solution. It worked perfectly once I used the normal DESKTOP-NAME\SQLEXPRESS server. I just did a complete uninstall, reinstalled using the normal express settings. Installed SSMS again and I was successfully able to connect Power BI Service to my desktop sql server via the gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install and use the normal SQL Server instead of LocalDB. When connecting to LocalDB, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically created and started, but I'm not sure that the Power BI Gateway supports that.