# Why do I have no TCP Port for my SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: tcp, ssms, sql-server-express

I went to computer management-> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLExpress -> TCP/IP but there is no TCP port. Is this normal? should I be assigning a number?.

[image]

Comment: Maybe (1) you have it listening at a specific address or (2) you have it listening with a Unix socket, not a TCP socket. Off topic.

Comment: @user207421 I don’t agree it’s off-topic, it’s about how to configure SQL Server Express for local development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like TCP/IP is disabled. It needs to be enabled in order to be assigned a port there. `Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS > TCP/IP` < right-click, `Enable`, restart service.

> [image]

^ When I enable this, I get a TCP/IP port; when it is disabled, it looks like your screenshot. Keep in mind you may not need to have TCP/IP enabled at all depending on how you are using the instance and you need to connect from.

Locally, you should be able to connect with `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` - connecting from another machine might depend on other factors like firewalls and network routing. If you continue having issues *even locally*, you need to validate that:

- the SQL Server instance is running
- the SQL Server Browser service is running
- remote connections are enabled
- you are connecting with the right instance name
- TCP/IP is enabled

Go through the troubleshooting steps (and links) in these places:

- [A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection)
- [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060667/61305)

Comment: Okay so I've followed the instructions and enabled TCP/IP. The ports IP1 to IP10 are all still blank including IPAll. Should I assign a random port number? and does IPAll represent IP's 1-10?. Thanks. Ultimately, what I'd like to be able to do is try to connect to my sql database using 'ip,portnumber'.

Comment: Why don’t you want to use `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` or `<ip>\SQLEXPRESS`? This is what most people do and is the default behavior.

Comment: I've tried the localhost\SQLEXPRESS but I had no idea about <ip>\SQLEXPRESS. I tried the <ip>\SQLEXPRESS. but I was unable to connect. I may be using the wrong IP address. I followed a youtube tutorial I opened command prompt-> typed: ipconfig-> and noted down the IPv4 Address. The reason I'm trying the different methods is because I'm trying to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181955/ssms-localdb-to-power-bi-gateway-not-connecting

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 0 so that `TCp Dynamic Ports` is blank/empty
Then enter a port into `TCP Port`, e.g. 1433
Then restart `sql server express` and `sql server browser`  in services control panel.  You should now be able to connect on the fixed port you entered.